# MFC CButton::Setcheck() grey box issue

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

When I use the `Setcheck()` under `CButton` class in `MFC`, a grey box is displayed in the menu item instead of a checkbox. The description is available at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31deb72x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you show us your code? Maybe there's something wrong with your code making such issue.

Comment: Have a screenshot?